# Why am I getting overfull with this parcolumns lstlisting?

Tags: warnings, parallel, parcolumns

I'm sure this is a simple question but would anybody be able to point out to me why the following generates overfull `\hbox` errors for the two `\colchunk` macros? It doesn't appear LaTeX needs to do any line breaking at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
 \colchunk{
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}]
movzx ebx, cx
push ebx
call someFunc
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
 }

 \colchunk{
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}]
mov ecx, edx
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
 }

 \colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on your usage, you can issue `\par` at the beginning of `\colchunk`, which takes care of the "Overfull `\hbox` warnings." You may have to adjust the vertical alignment then. However, there are other ways of performing this `parcolumns` approach that doesn't require such a fix. You could also use `\linewidth` for your `minipage`, which is marginally larger than `.45\textwidth` (by about `12.65pt`).

Comment: [Unrelated to your question] the `parcolumns` package allows you to form columns that can break across pages. Putting the content of a `colchunk` in a `minipage` negates this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option `nofirstindent` for the environment `parcolumns`. More information are given in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns)